# Question about avoiding Law of Excluded Middle

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory

I have little background in logic, so my apologies in advance if the following question is uninformed.

I was reading [this blog post](http://math.andrej.com/2009/09/08/constructive-stone-minima-of-sets-of-natural-numbers/) by Andrej Bauer,
and the first Proposition claims

> If every inhabited subset of NN has an infimum then the Law of Excluded middle holds.

Here I assume we are in some ambient elementary topos with NN its natural numbers object.

In the proof of the above, given a formula $\phi$ (in 0 variables) he constructs a particular subset of NN which is inhabited by 1; then by hypothesis he lets $m$ be its infimum, and he asserts $m\leq 1$.

After this we assume either $m=0$ or $m=1$; but doesn't this require using the Law of Excluded Middle? Which technique is being used to come to this conclusion at this step in the proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every natural $m \leq 1$ is either $0$ or $1$ by induction. For instance:

- $m = 0 \leq 1$ is $0$
- if $m = \mathsf{suc}\ n \leq 1$, then also $n \leq 1$, so the inductive hypothesis yields that $n$ is either $0$ or $1$. But actually it can only be $0$, because $\mathsf{suc}\ 1 = 2 \nleq 1$. So $m = \mathsf{suc}\ 0 = 1$.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand we can circumvent LEM here. I was wondering, do the elementary theorems about induction still hold without LEM? Also for the transfinite case?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Similar things to transfinite induction can be done constructively, but they generally lack the total ordering aspects of classical ordinals. Depending on what you use as your basis, induction may just be the basic substrate for most things (as in type theory), or it could be derived from other basic notions (frequent in set theory). Many times it's only necessary to be careful how you say something to not require LEM (i.e. pick the right option among several classically equivalent phrasings).

Comment: @IndraneelTambe Some forms of transfinite induction/recursion are perfectly valid; others are not. For instance, we can’t discuss a scheme which depends on knowing whether a given $x$ is a limit ordinal or a successor ordinal (and in fact, pinning down the meaning of “ordinal” is not trivial in constructive set theory). But ordinary theorems like induction, strong induction, lexicographic induction, etc. all work. There is a well-developed constructive theory of well-founded relations.